# Cucumber java throws single undefined step when other steps are working fine

Tags: java, spring, cucumber, gherkin

I have in my feature file the following step:

```
    Then Validate in total, how much is <firstCreditor> owed by everyone else. They are owed £<firstCreditorValue>
```

and in my steps definition class:

```
@Slf4j
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.DEFINED_PORT)
public class StepsDefinition {

    @Then("^Validate in total, how much is (.+) owed by everyone else. They are owed £(.d)$")
    public void validateCreditor1(String firstCreditor, double firstCreditorValue) throws Throwable {
    }
```

My Spec class:

```
package com.bsocial.integration;

import io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber;
import io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        strict = true,
        monochrome=true,
        plugin = {"pretty", "html:build/cucumber-reports"},
        tags = {"@myproject"},
        features = {"classpath:features/IntegrationTestRequest.feature"}
)
public class IntegrationTestRequestSpecs {

}
```

And my gradle config has:

```
    testCompile("io.cucumber:cucumber-core:${cucumberVersion}")
    testCompile("io.cucumber:cucumber-java8:${cucumberVersion}")
    testCompile("io.cucumber:cucumber-junit:${cucumberVersion}")
    testCompile("io.cucumber:cucumber-spring:${cucumberVersion}")
```

Where `cucumberVersion = '4.7.4'`.

But I still got the error:

```
The step "Validate in total, how much is David owed by everyone else. They are owed £2225.50" is undefined
io.cucumber.junit.UndefinedThrowable: The step "Validate in total, how much is David owed by everyone else. They are owed £2225.50" is undefined
```

I've read several posts here about this error, but the majority seems to be related to glue, which in my case I'm sure it's working as this is the only step that is giving me grief.

All other steps works just fine. I'm using a single feature file, a single Spec class and a single StepsDefinition class, all very vanilla, as I'm not even extending or implementing anything with my classes.

Is there anything I've missed checking?

Answer (score 0):

Turned out that the issue was in my Steps definition class.

I've changed the annotation from

```
    @Then("^Validate in total, how much is (.+) owed by everyone else. They are owed £(.d)$")
```

to

```
    @Then("^Validate in total, how much is (.*) owed by everyone else. They are owed £(.*)$")
```

Note: All other steps are using `(.+)` and `(.d)` just fine, it's just this step that had this issue. I was even wondering if I ended up with an invisible character when I copied the step from Word, or that I had some special character that was invalid (eg. £). I also thought that maybe, just maybe, Then had a different implementation from the other annotations and replaced it with an `And` to no luck.
I don't know why or how this works though, I did look the Gherkin regex guide and found nothing. Perhaps someone better informer can tell me what was the issue?